# RabbitMQ on Amazon EC2 Instance & Locally?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

Is it possible to setup a `RabbitMQ` server on an `Amazon EC2 instance`, and have of my machines at the office connect to this `RabbitMQ` server and send/receive messages to/from it?

Will I be charged by `Amazon` for the bandwidth / messages that flow into / out from my `RabbitMQ EC2  instance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's certainly possible and you will be charged for outbound traffic.

Comment: Thank you Oliver. Suppose that I created my `RabbitMQ` instance. Can other `Amazon EC2 instances` connect to it as well and send/receive messages to/from it? will this connection be secured?

Comment: Yes by default ONLY other instances can connect to it. You have to explicitely allow access from outside (internet) using the control panel or by script.