# Setting up rabbitMQ on AWS instance

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

I am having trouble setting up connection to a remote RabbitMQ server. 
Basically i have the consumer and the server running on a remote ubuntu machine and want my local machine to act as publisher. I have ssh access to the remote machine. I have read the answer to the following and it seems it is possible
[RabbitMQ on Amazon EC2 Instance & Locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791574/rabbitmq-on-amazon-ec2-instance-locally)

However when i try to connect to the remote host

```
connection = AMQP.connect(:host => 'hostname') 
puts "Connected to server...."
channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
queue = channel.queue(queue_name, :auto_delete => true)
exchange = channel.default_exchange
```

I get a 'Detected TCP connection failure'. i ran netstat on the remote server and the port 5672 is listening.

Answer (score 0):

Have you authorized the inbound traffic at port 5672 in the Security Group of your RabbitMQ server?

This may help:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html